How to restrict Istio sidecar not to loads lists of listner ports for few pods
In my setup there are multiple Microservices (MS) for example pod for this MS are (each pod is from unique MS) Pod1 to Pod10.
All of these pods are loading all the listners , route and clusters  exposed by each MS. This is what was expected.
But few of our MS's (say MS#1 and MS2) are exposing hell lot of ports/listeners which are not required by many other MS , for example MS#5,MS#6,MS#7 and MS#8 do not require to pay any kind of attention to listeners , routes and clusters.
As per standard configuration and working these exuberant listner openings are creating following issues :

Increases RAM and CPU usage of all the PODs of this NameSPace (NS).
As explained these listner by MS#1 and MS#2 are needed by few pods (may be 5%) of total system , but these are increasing the RAM and CPU need for all the sidecars of each PODs.
Infact, this increases the static RAM and CPU and the increase will on traffic will be on top of this.

There are situation that , MS#1 and MS#2 can not reduce their listener count.
This
I went through various documentation but based of workload exclusion , I do not find any reference for exclusion of ports for specific MicroService.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
